# Pyinstaller Python3 Windows10 - App will not start from .bat script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, pyinstaller

Using Python3 and Pyinstaller on Windows 10... I created an app that runs fine when double clicking on it or when running it directly from the command line. However, it only works with the command line from inside of the working directory (its home directory). I want to use Windows scheduler to launch the app periodically. When the time came that it was supposed to launch,  The CMD window briefly flashed and the program quit. So I ran it from the terminal using `c:\mydir\my.exe`

I got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "email2.py", line 12, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pic.jpeg'
[10188] Failed to execute script my.exe
```

I checked. The `pic.jpeg` file is still there.

Just for a workaround I created a file called `start.bat`and placed it inside the working directory. All I did was call the program with `My.exe`. Again it runs fine from inside of the directory but not from outside.

Bottom line I just want to schedule the program to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `pic.jpeg` as part of your `my.exe` bundle. Try adding:

```
datas=[('pix.jpeg', '.')],
```

under the `Analysis` part of your `.spec` file. Also, make sure you are producing a `onefile` bundle.

Comment: Could you give me a few more details please. I changed the spec file and ran Pyinstaller like this pyinstaller --onefile myfile.spec ... I get the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'akespec' ...Did I type the command correctly?

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, however still getting the same result. Any other ideas?